# PDOを使用しているlocalhostのページにアクセスできない。

Tags: php, mysql, apache

よろしくお願いします。

もともとXAMPPを入れており、その時からPDOを利用していました。
今回、とある理由でXAMPPをアンインストールし、Apacheを入れました。

データベース関係はPDOを使用したいので、今回もphp.iniを編集して、
既に作ってあるDB連携をしているページをlocalhostで開こうとしたのですが、
「このウェブページにはアクセスできません」と表示されました。

試しにDB連携をしていないページと、
DBを利用しているコードをコメントアウトしたものを開いてみましたが、
どちらもちゃんと表示されました。

php/extの中に、
php_pdo.dll,php_pdo_mysql.dll
があることも確認しています。

phpinfo()にも、PDOとpdo_mysqlの記述が追加されていました。

php.iniの記述です。

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

DB接続用のコードです。

```
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=iiidb',
        $username,
        $password,
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

確認すべきことは他に何かありますか？
試すべきことがあれば教えていただきたいです。

最終的には、PDOを使ったデータベースと連携しているページが表示されるようにしたいです。

環境は

windows8.1
PHP5.2.11
Apache2.2.14

となっています。

情報が少しでも欲しいので、気がついたことがあれば
教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

余談(？)ですが、
Apache Service Monitorの下の方に「Win32」と書かれているのが
少しきになりますが、無関係なのでしょうか...
（私のPCは64bit）

私のPCのは学校の斡旋で、今回入れたApacheは
学校側で授業で使用するために生徒に配布しているもので、
今回は特別に教師の人が入れてくださいました。

追記：
試して分かった事を書いていきます。

・ファイアウォールを切ってみましたが、結果は同じでした。
・プログラムにエラーが存在する場合、エラーメッセージが表示されます。
・データベースへの接続は確認出来ました。
・DELETE文の実行は確認出来ました。
・SELECT文のみ、ページが表示されなくなります。

Comment: ええと、もしかして MySQL サーバは XAMPP に含まているものを使っていたのではないですか？ そうだとすれば XAMPP のアンイストール時に一緒に削除されてしまったのではないでしょうか…

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
MySQLはXAMPPとは別に入れてあります。
先ほど確認したときのエラーはこちらのミスでして、今確認し直した所、ログインも出来、作成してあるデータベースなども全て存在していました。

Answer (score 1):

> ・DELETE文の実行は確認出来ました。
>   ・SELECT文のみ、ページが表示されなくなります。

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=iiidb',
        $username,
        $password,
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

    // add
    $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // select~ statement
    ....
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
setAttributeが理解できていないので調べてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

コメント、回答ありがとうございます。

phpのバージョンを上げたことで解決しました。